# On Hudson, how can I set a build on the job list to "not delete", since it is a "release candidate"?

Tags: build, hudson, purge

On Hudson I have a job when I'm setting the property "Discard Old Builds" as true.
In some cases I want to mantain the build ever, since it is in production and I need to maintain the rastreability. For example: builds #1, #2 and #3 could be purged; build #4 must be maintaned, since it is on production; build #5, #6 and #7 could be purged.

Is there a way to "check" a build to be "not deleted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go to the build page in Hudson and click the "Keep this build forever" button at the top right.  This can also be automated via the keep-build command in the [Hudson CLI](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Hudson/Command-line_interface).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!! I don't found this option. Is this parameter available on 2.2.1 version?

Comment: You should see the button if you have "Discard old builds" set up for your job - is that not the case ?

Comment: Yes, this is my case. The only button that I found on the build page is "ENABLE AUTO REFRESH" at the top right.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that - I'm mostly familiar with Jenkins rather than Hudson and assumed that Hudson would have the same option.

Comment: I think you didn't clicked the specific build, i am Hudson 2.2.1 and I have this option without special plugin

Comment: Gareth, Daniel, thanks for your reply. I'm still without this link/button. Is possible that only admin users have this option? Do you know if it's a parameter that can be set in manage page?

Comment: it shouldn't be an admin thing and I don't know any parameter.
to make it clear you are looking it on the page of the specific build under the specific job right?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yes. I'm looking in the specific build page. To be sure, I've installed a new version of Hudson (3.1.1) in my local machine and I found the button "Keep this build forever" as you said. So thanks for your replies. Now I need to see the Hudson setup on my server to understand why it don't appear. Just to be clear, it was another colleague that did the server's Hudson setup and I need to correct this option.

Comment: Ah, if your Hudson has security enabled, I think you will need Update permission for the Run object (which is a synonym for build) in order to see the "keep forever" button.

Comment: Gareth, you're right!! It's exactly what I need. It's working now. Thank's a lot you and Daniel.